# Visitor pattern, not all visitors have a reasonable implementations for all methods in the interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, visitor-pattern

I have an interface `Serializable`. This class have methods for each `Item` subclass in my application. However not all classes that implements `Serializable` have a reasonable implementation of the `serialize` method. Some of the serializers should not be able to serialize all the different objects because of security constraints in my application.

How should I solve this? Should I serialize a message that says *"Serializer can't serialize object because of security constraints."* or should I throw an RuntimeException? Or are there other ways of "fixing" this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would violate one important principle with your logic: [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html)

> The Interface Segregation Principle states that clients should not be
>   forced to implement interfaces they don't use. Instead of one fat
>   interface many small interfaces are preferred based on groups of
>   methods, each one serving one submodule.

So, I would create two distinct base classes to achieve your requirement:

- `Item`
- `SerializableItem`

And your visitor would only rely on `SerializableItem` objects:

```
public void visit(SerializableItem sItem)
```

Of course, it is possible to gather **only** common behaviour (unrelated to serialization so) of both classes within a kind of `AbstractItem`, as long as the visitor doesn't deal with it.

Comment: But the problem is not that the items being forced to implement the Serializable interface. The problem is that some of the Visitor's (Serializers) does not have any reasonable way to serialize it.

Comment: @Laidback Andy Hence the fact to let visitor deal with `SerializableItem` because solely this type is supposed to implement a complete implementation of serialization. Your problem would thus disappear since `Item` objects (not supposing to correspond to a full serialization way) aren't used by visitor. For better understanding and to avoid confusion, replace `SerializableItem`by `ItemSubjectToAFullSerialization`

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how it solves what I am asking. Could you provide an example where you have two serializers that inherit from the same serialize interface. Let say the interface for being serializable have two methods, but only the first serializer is able to provide a decent implementation for both. The other is only able to provide an implementation for the first one.

Comment: @Laidback Andy "where you have two serializers that inherit from the same serialize interface". What I promote is to avoid the common inheritance. Instead, create two interfaces like `FullySerializable` and `PartiallySerializable`. `FullySerializable`interface EXTENDS `PartiallySerializable`. So you will end up with a `PartiallySerializable` declaring the common `method1` and `FullySerializable` adding `method2`. Likewize, you will have two types of `Item`: Item1 implementing the first interface (since partially serializable) and Item2 (since fully serializable) implementing the other.

Comment: Just one thing; Does it seem right that a `AdminJsonSerializer` inherits from `MobileJsonSerializer`. The mobile JSON serializer is more restrictive with the fields it serialize. Should they be two separate interfaces instead? And have distinctive method headers? Such as `toAdminJson(Item item)` and `toMobileJson(Item item)`.

Comment: @Laidback Andy: If there isn't a strict IS-A relationship, prefer creating two distinct hierarchies of interfaces. In your case, `AdminJsonSerializer` can be seen as an extension of `MobileJsonSerializer`since less restrictive, so extending it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing `UnsupportedOperationException("Non serializable")` is a first guess. Of course it would be awesome to discover that at compile time, but Visitor pattern was not designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

A class that won't provide a reasonable implementation for `Serializable` shouldn't implement it. Anyway the question is quite unclear. Does the interface `Serializable` declare the `accept()` method in your setup? It shouldn't. If it is possible that unserializable items are a special subclass of item you could just not implement the `visit(MyNotSerializableItem)` in the Visitor.

Comment: It is some of the serializers that may not have a reasonable implementation.